# Split zip file by directory using Linux or Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, zip

I have a huge zip file (100GB) with this file structure:

```
rsna/
    train/
        ...
    test/
        ...
```

Within the "train" and "test" directories are a bunch of image files with no other child directories. How can I split the directory into a "train" zip with all the train images and a "test" zip with all the test images?

I don't have much space left on my computer so I can't do anything that takes up more space (like duplicating the zip file).

Comment: Maybe delete the files while you are adding them into the train / test zip files, but sounds risky as if it fails, then you lost the info.

Comment: I believe this is the correct step forward. Load the zip. Delete unneeded data and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, the only way is to follow this algorithm:

```
1. Add the file to compress within the corresponding zip file
2. Delete the file that was just added
3. Repeat until all files have been compressed and all the original files have been processed and deleted
4. Finally, pray there's no issue and your data don't get lost due to this algorithm. I guess you can re-download that information again from an external source...
```